# How to extract a particular pattern from a String

Tags: java

I have a excel sheet , i am parsing the excel sheet line by line

where i will get the string in this format

```
query at.mycollection ntoreturn:1 reslen:1833 nscanned:1  nquery: { like_symbol: "SC!JNJ" }  nreturned:1 bytes:1817etc...
```

I am trying to extract only the nquery from the string, so that the output must look like

```
nquery: { like_symbol: "SC!JNJ" }
```

I have tried this way

```
System.out.println(s.split("nscanned:1")[1]);
```

The output i got is

**nquery: { like_symbol: "SC!JNJ" }  nreturned:1 bytes:1817etc....**

Comment: Is the value after `nquery:` always quoted using `{` and `}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `substring`:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String str = "query at.mycollection ntoreturn:1 reslen:1833 nscanned:1  nquery: { like_symbol: \"SC!JNJ\" }  nreturned:1 bytes:1817etc...";

    int index = str.indexOf("nquery:");
    int index2 = str.indexOf("nreturned:1");

    // some validation 
    if(index != -1 && index2 != -1 && index < index2){
        String str2 = str.substring(index, index2);

        str2 = str2.trim();

        System.out.println(str2);
    }
    else{
        System.err.println("Something wrong here");
    }
}
```

Output: `nquery: { like_symbol: "SC!JNJ" }`

Actually, regex is good for more complicated cases but if you have the same structure like you posted, `substring`  will be enough

Comment: Normally I would recommend regex, but after viewing the answer not in this case. However, is nreturned always going to be nreturned:1? I would guess not, so you may wish to restrict the second indexOf to "nreturned:".

Comment: @JaredBeekman, whats the regex version of above code? I feel comfortable with regex.

Comment: I suck at building regex to be quite honest. I always use some online evaluator or another based on the language I happen to be using. This link is for a Java one: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try indexOf and subsequently substring